# Semisimple Lie algebras are perfect.

Tags: lie-algebras

Can anyone explain why a semi-simple finite dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ has to be perfect ?

The natural way to prove something like that would be to look to the algebra generated by the Lie brackets, which when $\mathfrak{g}$ is not perfect would be expected to be solvable. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: finite dimensional?

Comment: I have only seen this as a corollary to the fact that semisimple Lie algebras are a direct sum of simple ideals.

Comment: Finite dimensional naturally.

Comment: Note that all answers assume characteristic $0$. For a counterexample in positive characteristic, see https://math.jhu.edu/~sakellar/automorphic-files/liestructure.pdf, remark 2.2.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semi simple Lie algebra. Then $\mathfrak{g}$ can be written as direct sum of simple ideals.

For simplicity, we can write $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus\mathfrak{g}_2$ where $\mathfrak{g}_1,\mathfrak{g}_2$ are simple ideals.

We then have $$[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]=[\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus \mathfrak{g}_2, \mathfrak{g}_1\oplus \mathfrak{g}_2]= [\mathfrak{g}_1,\mathfrak{g}_1]\oplus [\mathfrak{g}_2,\mathfrak{g}_2]=\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus \mathfrak{g}_2=\mathfrak{g}$$

See that $\mathfrak{g}_1=[\mathfrak{g}_1, \mathfrak{g}_1], \mathfrak{g}_2=[\mathfrak{g}_2,\mathfrak{g}_2]$ as $\mathfrak{g}_1,\mathfrak{g}_2$ are simple ideals. Thus, we have $\mathfrak{g}=[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way (and I have not been able to think of an easier way) is the following:

Note that here I will assume this to be over $\mathbb{C}$.

That semisimple Lie algebras are perfect follows as a corollary to the theorem that such a Lie algebra is a direct sum of simple ideals. It is then clear as no non-trivial quotient of such a direct sum can be abelian.

Comment: I do not understand “no non-trivial quotient of such a direct sum can be abelian”. I am not able to relate this with the result.

Comment: @cello Which part? That the claim holds, or that the claim leads to the Lie algebra being perfect?

Comment: That the claim holds.

Comment: @cello Because any proper ideal will be a direct sum of some number of copies of those ideals (if we pick them correctly at least, to avoid issues with diagonals and so on). It might be a bit less clear than I realized while writing it, and I find your way more direct.

Comment: Thanks for compliment. I would try to understand your idea spending some time. Will come back and ask you if I still have some doubt. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use the fact that a quotient of $\mathfrak{g}$ (a finite dimension semisimple Lie algebra over a field with characteristic $0$) is semisimple,  then there is an easy answer. The usual way to prove this fact is to use Cartan's criterion: see [here](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/mcgerty/Lie12/Lecture9.pdf).

If $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple, then its quotient $\mathfrak{g}/[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$ is also semisimple. But this is abelian, so $\mathfrak{g}/[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}] = 0$, then $\mathfrak{g} =[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$.

Answer (score -2):

here you can find some relevant discussion.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60498/lie-algebra-semisimple

Comment: There does not seem to be anything at all there about this question. The question there is the reverse.